# Why if Google Chrome crashing with UTMZ Google Analytics links?

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

I am setting up cross-domain tracking between a wordpress site and a volusion shopping cart. So setting onclick events on relevant links to shopping cart. Links end up looking like:

```
http://www.OurShop.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=5555
&__utma=189569076.309469758.1326827732.1330098691.1330101003.18
&__utmb=189569076.4.10.1330101003&__utmc=189569076
&__utmx=-
&__utmz=189569076.1328718473.13.3.utmcsr=Newsletter%2B92|utmccn=website%20content|utmcmd=email|utmctr=saw%20palmetto%20pcos|utmcct=content-link-1
&__utmv=-
&__utmk=30063551
```

This works as expected in Safari, Firefox and IE. With some irony, the link above makes Chrome 17 crash really hard (have not tested IE with ChromeFrame). The page loads, but the progress arc keeps spinning, and links are unresponsive on the page. Eventually the "kill pages / wait" dialog appears.

If I remove the utmz variables of the url, and keep utmv and utmk the link then works in Chrome, but there is a very long load time on the page. Removing utmk speeds up the load time it seems and the page also loads.

If I keep the utmz string of variables, and drop utmv and utmk, Chrome hangs the same way as described above. So, the utmz seems to be the main issue, with utmk perhaps a secondary issue.

On both sites have pretty straightforward GATCs with just setAllowLinker and setAllowAnchor enabled (setAllowAnchor inorder to not use the `?` delimiter since Volusion uses this in their store urls.)

Can not run the developer tools when the page loads, that also breaks... people must be running into this with cross domain tracking setups? Since the links work in other browsers, doesn't seem to be a Volusion issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you misunderstand _setAllowHash. It doesn't matter if you already have '?' on the url or not, GA will be able to work either way. _setAllowHash is a deprecated function to a completely different issue, and by enabling it you're not doing anything since it's enabled by default. If you disable it on the other hand _setAllowHash(false), than you disable the domain hash (that's the first number on the __utm* cookies). All this is of course completely irrelevant to your issue here. I just wanted to let you know that.

Comment: What if you have __utmz with a direct source? `__utmz=189569076.1328718473.13.3.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)`

Comment: Sorry, Eduardo I meant setAllowAnchor... editing post

Comment: Tried changing the utmz variables as suggested: same behavior, page loads but not completely, eventually get the kill page/ wait dialog.

Comment: But if you are setting _setAllowLinker, true than you should be setting _Link(url, true) as well. So the cookies are appended to the Anchor instead of the query parameters. Than your urls will look like this: `http://www.OurShop.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=5555
#__utma=189569076.309469758.1326827732.1330098691.1330101003.18
&__utmb=189569076.4.10.1330101003&__utmc=189569076
&__utmx=-
&__utmz=189569076.1328718473.13.3.utmcsr=Newsletter%2B92|utmccn=website%20content|utmcmd=email|utmctr=saw%20palmetto%20pcos|utmcct=content-link-1
&__utmv=-
&__utmk=30063551`

Comment: Thanks Eduardo - that is really unclear in the Google docs. So, in my links I now have: `onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', this.href, true]); return false;"` which produces the pound sign URLs -- and... Chrome still crashes the same. What kind of diagnostic tools could I use here? I can email you an actual link if you are curious to see what is happening ....

Comment: Sure could help a lot to have a link to test this out. But after my previous comments I now believe it's not ga.js that is crashing, but something else on the page that is running and reading thoese parameters.

Comment: I'm thinking this too...

Comment: So, tried disabling different things, and it seems like the problem is with something called Power Reviews and the javascript it loads. In particular, I think the problem lies in a file called dakota.js.

Comment: Now that I see this, I also see that the reviews don't load on the page when Google crashes, how would you have some conditional `<!-- if Google Chrome , wait until Power Reviews is done loading, then load GATC -->`  or the other way around?